# sort by group using max value of each group

Tags: r

Is there a way to sort by group using decreasing max value of each group, and sorting within group by decreasing value?

Input

```
 x <- read.table(text = "Name Value 
                         A    20    
                         A    40   
                         A    35   
                         B    70    
                         B    80   
                         B    90    
                         C    10   
                         C    20  
                         C    30 ", header = T)
```

Output

```
Name Value 
B    90    
B    80   
B    70   
A    40    
A    35   
A    20    
C    30   
C    20  
C    10
```

Comment: I guess there's a dupe somewhere, but a base R idiom is `x[with(x, order(-ave(Value, Name, FUN = max))),]`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Group by Name, make a temporary column and then arrange by it and value

```
df %>% group_by(Name) %>% 
  mutate(mx = max(Value)) %>% 
  arrange(desc(mx), desc(Value)) %>% 
  select(-mx)
```

Comment: Hope you may find it worth to note that I've added a [benchmark](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45360893/3817004).

Answer (score 5):

#### Edit: Corrections and benchmark

During preparation of the benchmark, I noticed that some of my solutions only worked with the partially ordered sample data supplied by the OP but failed with arbitrarily shuffled data. I have removed these from my answer but they are still available from the history.

The added benchmark section compares the base R, the `data.table`, and both `dpylr` solutions on two different problem sizes.

---

For the sake of completeness, here are two `data.table` and one base R solutions:

#### 1. `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
X <- data.table(x)
X[, tmp := max(Value), by = Name][order(-tmp, -Value)][, tmp := NULL][]
```

> ```
>    Name Value
> 1:    B    90
> 2:    B    80
> 3:    B    70
> 4:    A    40
> 5:    A    35
> 6:    A    20
> 7:    C    30
> 8:    C    20
> 9:    C    10
> ```

@Frank suggested a more concise `data.table` solution:

```
X <- data.table(x)
X[order(-Value), .SD, by = Name]
```

This works because after sorting *The order of the rows within each group is preserved, as is the order of the groups.* (`help("data.table"` on the `by` parameter)

#### 2. base R

This is a modification of [Frank's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45359943/r-sort-by-group-using-max-value-of-each-group#comment77681652_45359943):

```
x[with(x, order(-ave(Value, Name, FUN = max), -Value)), ]
```

> ```
>   Name Value
> 6    B    90
> 5    B    80
> 4    B    70
> 2    A    40
> 3    A    35
> 1    A    20
> 9    C    30
> 8    C    20
> 7    C    10
> ```

#### Benchmark

In order to run the benchmark for different problem sizes, we need to make up sample data:

```
library(magrittr)
library(data.table)

# prepare data
n_rows <- 1E1
set.seed(1234L)
x0 <- data.frame(
  Name = sample(LETTERS[seq_len(min(round(n_rows/3), length(LETTERS)))], n_rows, TRUE),
  Value = sample(n_rows))
# coerce to data.table
X0 <- data.table(x0)
```

Some solutions change the data in place, so each run is started with a fresh copy. The copy operation is timed as well.

```
# run benchmarks
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  copy = x <- copy(x0),
  base_avg = {
    x <- copy(x0)
    x[with(x, order(-ave(Value, Name, FUN = max), -Value)),]
  },
  dt_tmp = {
    X <- copy(X0)
    X[, tmp := max(Value), by = Name][order(-tmp, -Value)][, tmp := NULL][]
  },
  dt_SD = {
    X <- copy(X0)
    X[order(-Value), .SD, by = Name]
  },
  dplyr_rt = {
    copy(x0) %>% 
      dplyr::group_by(Name) %>% 
      dplyr::mutate(mx = max(Value)) %>% 
      dplyr::arrange(desc(mx), desc(Value)) %>% 
      dplyr::select(-mx)
  },
  dplyr_loki = {
    copy(x0) %>% 
      dplyr::group_by(Name) %>%  # group by Name
      dplyr::mutate(NameMax = max(Value)) %>%  # create a temp variable holding the max of each Name
      dplyr::arrange(desc(NameMax), desc(Value)) %>%  # arrange with two columns
      dplyr::select(Name, Value) # select only the two input columns
  },
  times = 100L
)
```

Below are the results for two different problem sizes of 10 rows and 1 M rows.

With just 10 rows (which is mainly measuring overhead),

> ```
> Unit: microseconds
>        expr      min        lq       mean    median        uq       max neval  cld
>        copy   12.839   19.8235   23.69004   24.1660   27.9415    38.892   100 a   
>    base_avg  149.145  193.5115  256.32913  227.8710  243.5400  2180.155   100 a   
>      dt_tmp  951.883 1046.2780 1185.33735 1175.2215 1256.9685  1903.387   100  b  
>       dt_SD  758.184  827.2810 1386.55800  970.0065 1035.5170 40170.486   100  b  
>    dplyr_rt 7329.984 7700.2025 8107.00109 7925.8075 8273.7485 11631.389   100   c 
>  dplyr_loki 8650.386 9059.3065 9820.92511 9269.0525 9745.3710 33805.600   100    d
> ```

base R is clearly the fastest, followed by both `data.table` approaches, and both `dplyr` approaches last. The difference between the `dplyr` is interesting. It seems that `dplyr::select(-mx)` is faster, i.e., has less overhead than `dplyr::select(Name, Value)` which is the only difference in the code.

With 1 M rows (`n_rows <- 1E6`),

> ```
> Unit: milliseconds
>        expr        min         lq       mean     median         uq        max neval  cld
>        copy   1.378927   1.809747   2.404129   2.268131   2.374798   5.561016    11 a   
>    base_avg 131.783388 143.402694 207.434114 255.460485 259.142658 276.782117    11   c 
>      dt_tmp  70.030740  72.104982  84.694791  75.020852  76.197961 192.827694    11  b  
>       dt_SD  53.406217  55.149698  58.090283  58.156189  60.084684  67.835483    11  b  
>    dplyr_rt 752.707729 779.147098 821.327276 809.360011 878.231387 895.566707    11    d
>  dplyr_loki 747.559410 765.500369 792.089826 793.458180 803.056861 895.127580    11    d
> ```

both `data.table` solutions are about 4 times faster than the base R approach and more than 10 times faster than the `dplyr` solutions with an advantage for *dt_SD*. The large difference between *dplyr_rt* and *dplyr_loki* is gone, now it seems that *dplyr_loki* is somewhat faster.

Comment: @Frank Benchmark shows your `data.table` approach is fastest.

Comment: nice summary. I referenced your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `dplyr` solution. See @UweBlock's answer for a benchmark.

```
library(dplyr)
x %>% group_by(Name) %>%  # group by Name
      mutate(NameMax = max(Value)) %>%  # create a temp variable holding the max of each Name
      arrange(desc(NameMax), desc(Value)) %>%  # arrange with two columns
      select(Name, Value) # select only the two input columns

#     Name Value
#    <fctr> <int>
# 1      B    90
# 2      B    80
# 3      B    70
# 4      A    40
# 5      A    35
# 6      A    20
# 7      C    30
# 8      C    20
# 9      C    10
```

Comment: Hope you may find it worth to note that I've added a [benchmark](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45360893/3817004).